# Could not load file or assembly 'DropDownCheckBoxes' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint-2013, .net-assembly, assembly-references

We have added third party ([DropdownCheckBoxes](https://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/discussions/663289)) dll reference in our SharePoint web part application.

On the user control, registered this assembly as

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DropDownCheckBoxes" Namespace="Saplin.Controls" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

When we run it on browser, it giving us error as --

Could not load file or assembly 'DropDownCheckBoxes' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can you please guide what needs to be done for this? 
Thank You!

Comment: I've downloaded the library, added it to my bin folder, added that line to the page and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dear. You mean you added whole project into bin folder or just dlls within the folder? And did u mean library means the source code of "dropdowncheckboxes" implementation for codeplex?

Comment: I added just the `DropdownCheckBoxes.dll` library to the `bin` folder of my project and registered the assembly just like in your question and it worked.

Comment: Great. I tried the same thing too. Not sure why it doesn't working for me.

Comment: I've downloaded the library [here](https://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/downloads/get/264125). Maybe there is a difference...

Comment: Hello dear, confirmed. the dll is same from where you downloaded, have u tried by adding register assembly line in sharepoint visual web application? or asp,net application?

Comment: Hi,click on the "Package" in the solution. In this package you can add the existing dlls. It will place those assemblies in GAC.

Comment: For me it was an asp.net application.